# Format date in excel to drop time part for midnight datetimes

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to create a custom format to format following values as follows:

```
1/2/2003 05:06:07 -> 1/2/2003 05:06:07
1/2/2003 00:00:01 -> 1/2/2003 00:00:01
1/2/2003 00:00:00 -> 1/2/2003
```

I know there is a way to provide different number formats for <0, =0, >0 cases. Is there something like that for datetimes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that with a single number format, instead you must use two conditional formatting rules.

Add rules by going to Conditional Formatting >> New Rule >> Use a formula to determine which cells to format.

This is for non-midnight times.
 Formula `=MOD(A1,1)<>0` 
 Number format: `m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss`

This is for midnight times.
 Formula `=MOD(A1,1)=0` 
 Number format: `m/d/yyyy`

Comment: imho, it would be simpler to format all the cells as `m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss` and add one conditional formatting rule for `=MOD(A1,1)=0` with `m/d/yyyy` ;)

Answer (score 2):

As already noted by Kyle, you must use Conditional Formatting. You could apply the default **m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss** formatting as usual, then just create one conditional formatting rule for the range, so you conditionally format values as **m/d/yyyy** only where time is 0.

Kyle's formula is most elegant (`MOD(A1,1)=0`), or you could also use something like the following:

```
=HOUR(A1)+MINUTE(A1)+SECOND(A1)=0
```